# Fragment inflater Error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I got a problem with the android programming. I'm trying to learn how to use Fragments. So i'm doing it programmatically.

This is my Activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    BlankFragment firstFragment = new BlankFragment();
    ft.add(R.id.container, firstFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

And this is Activity's layout:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"></FrameLayout>
```

My fragment has it's own layout which is a simple textview inside a relative layout.
So i got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: fragments.marco.it.copiausingfrag.MainActivity@4c36ed9 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fragments.marco.it.copiausingfrag/fragments.marco.it.copiausingfrag.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: fragments.marco.it.copiausingfrag.MainActivity@4c36ed9 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Can someone help me? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your onAttach method on your Fragment, you're probably throwing an Exception yourself if the parent Activity doesn't implement said interface (*OnFragmentInteractionListener*)

Comment: Yes, and no. Read : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html .
One way of communication between activities and fragments is having the activity implement an interface, and when the fragment is  attached, check if the activity it is attached into implements that interface. That ensures that the activity has all the methods that are in the interface, and that the fragment can call them safely.  
But if you aren't implementing communication between them, then you can simply delete that code, the interface and remove the callback entirely.